# ORA-01847 error when not using dates in the query

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g

I'm trying to run this query in an Oracle 11g database:

```
SELECT * FROM BALANCE B
WHERE B.EMPLOY_ID = '0016'
AND B.PROJETCT_ID = '5TM-1305002.01.01.01'
```

but the following error is displayed:

```
ORA 01847 : day of the month must be between 1 and last day of the month
```

The `EMPLOY_ID` field is `varchar2(4)` and the `PROJECT_ID` is a `varchar2(20)`.

I do not understand why the Oracle database is trying to convert the parameter values to date values. What is going on?

Comment: Is `balance` a view rather than a table? If so can you add the view definition to the question.

Comment: Also, if EMPLOY_ID is varchar2(4), your current where clause will yield no results as you have leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Hmmm, I can only imagine this happening on a `select` if `balance` is a view or if it has virtual columns.

Comment: What are the columns/datatypes that you are selecting? Perhaps you have a date column with bad data in it.

Comment: If it is a table, do you have fine grained auditing defined for it? Maybe it has a handler which is converting something and you have unexpected data (e.g. if the project ID is supposed to encode date). Otherwise maybe data corruption is a possibility. Does it only fail on these specific values, and if so can you give an example of parameters that are OK?

Comment: dvsoukup you're right! this space came when I paste the code, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @bjones, I did not realize that a field that was trying to convert to date was in trouble in the table data.

TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (Bal.DATE_DISP, 'DD / MM / YY'), 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS BUDAT.

When I comment on this field, the error is not shown again.

Comment: So you aren't actually doing `select *`, or using the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try this?

> SELECT * FROM BALANCE B
>
> WHERE TO_CHAR(B.EMPLOY_ID) = '0016'
>
> AND TO_CHAR(B.PROJETCT_ID) = '5TM-1305002.01.01.01'

Comment: The question says both columns are already strings, why would `to_char()` help? Anyway, seems the problem is in something the OP left out of the question.

Comment: It would determine if "balance" is a view or not

Comment: returns the same error , I did not pay attention to the fact that the problem was in a cast of a field that was in the query.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to invalid data in one of date columns in table.

You can check your query with rownum condition, just to make sure that the where clause is correct or not.

If it is working then there is no because of B.EMPLOY_ID and B.PROJETCT_ID columns.

Comment: The OP has already said in a comment that it's because of unexpected data in a string column they're converting to date, which they hadn't shown in the question.

Comment: Exactly the problem was a field that contained a value that was not date